# Unexpected space between views in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, spacing

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_send_imageView"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp">

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_send_mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

On my device it looks like this:
[image]
As you can see there are two "dividers" - one is between the top border of the application window and ImageView and the second is between the ImageView and MapView. I've set the paddings/margins to 0 - no luck. What can I do about it?

Comment: try scaletype = fitxy for ur imageview

Comment: it is happenning due the image. try @TamilselvanKalimuthu's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your image view

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_send_imageView"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:padding="0dp"/>
```

Comment: Yes, andjustViewBounds and (especially) scaleType did the trick. I'll accept the answer as soon as SO allow me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If it works then don't forgot to tick the right mark for the answer